# Any Chance of JApplicationWebClient constants changing in the future?

Tags: joomla-api, browser

I'm building a component that store info about the client and it stores only the numbers of the `JApplicationWebClient` constants instead the browser name, system name, etc, .

But if the constants change, things will get a bit messy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, software does change.

To somehow **reverse the order of constants**, so that `CHROME` is renamed from 19 to 5, would make little sense to me and **very unlikely to happen.**

Generally things change so that a problem can be solved (taking into account b/c). I would rather say there is a risk of this class being deprecated on the long run sometime later (Joomal 4 or Joomla 5) for whatever reasons.

**Looking at the history of this class** (since 2011), there have been little changes done (just additions), even since the Joomla Platform times till the new Joomla Framework. So I would say you are on the safe side, at least in 3.x and the foreseeable 4.x based on the Joomla Framework.

**My advice**: until you don't have a problem, don't spend your time fixing it (aka don't build on top of JApplicationWebClient if the current functionality works fine). If you need to read this information years later (5 -10 years), maybe from non-Joomla applications, maybe you should store strings (if storage is not an issue).

You should first start to worry when this class is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can change. I think it's not highly probable.

Nevertheless, you have to implement an abstraction layer to avoid any impact, or support several versions of JApplication clients.